# Очочки или очёчки?

Tags: орфография

У Высоцкого: На стене висели в рамках бородатые мужчины —
Все в **очечках** на цепочках, по-народному — в пенсне.

Ленинград: Мне, короче, Собчак – никак, Мне никак, Собчак, короче. Но **очёчи** у ней ништяк, Очень чётенькие **очёчи**.

Но: Вопрос № 240081  Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно пишется - "**очёчки" или "очочки**" (имеются в виду очки)? Спасибо.
Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Правильно: **очочки**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После ж, ч, ш, щ для передачи ударного гласного о пишется буква о или ё.
Буква о пишется в следующих случаях.

На месте беглого гласного о в именах существительных и прилагательных, напр.: жор, обжора, прожорливый (ср. жрать), жом (ср. жму), ожог, поджог, пережог, изжога (ср. жгу, жгла); рожон (ср. род. п. рожна), шов (шва); княжон (род. п. мн. ч. от княжна), ножо́н (род. п. от ножны́ — устар. вариант слова но́жны), мошон, мошонка (род. п. мн. ч. и уменьш. от мошна), кишок, кишочки (род. п. и уменьш. от кишки), квашонка (уменьш. от квашня), кошомка и кошомный (от кошма), ***очочки (от очки),*** очочко (от очко),

См.: [ПАС](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=17#pp17)

Comment: Тогда  почему в указанных  известных текстах пишут "очечки"?  Как-то это можно объяснить? Это же не  записки в Сети, наверное, люди тоже грамотные писали.

Comment: Наверное, у Высоцкого ошибка. Ср. кишки - кишок - кишочки

Comment: _Серж: Ср. кишки - **кишок** - кишочки_ === А с каким производным от слова **очки**  Вы предлагаете сравнивать второе слово в Вашей цепочке? _**Кишок** -- ???_

Comment: @ slava1947, ничем не предлагаю сравнивать. Не во всех словах можно привести тройную цепочку. Очки - очочки, кишки -кишок -кишочки.

Answer (score 5):

> ***Очочки*** или ***очёчки?***

На сегодняшний день правильны оба написания. Почему? Потому что и  ***очочки*** и ***очёчки*** есть в современных словарях.

По поводу  Высоцкого… Не согласен с этим комментарием Сержа:

> Наверное, у Высоцкого ошибка.

Но почему же ошибка-то?  Во времена Высоцкого не существовало ещё ни **ПАС** (см. **[§ 18.5](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=18#pp18)**), ни **["Русского орфографического словаря"](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8&all=x)**, зафиксировавших написание слова ***очочки*** с буквой ***О***…

А существовали в то время **Правила-56**, которым написание слова ***очёчки*** с ***Ё*** нисколько не противоречило. Правила *"На месте беглого гласного О в именах существительных…"*, появившегося спустя несколько десятилетий в ПАС, в Правилах-56 **не было**.

А что в них было? А было это:

> **[§ 4.](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/114-gl-19-1)** А. Если после ***ж, ч, ш, щ*** под ударением произносится ***о***, то буква ***о*** пишется:
>
> <там то и там то>.
>
> **Во всех прочих случаях** после ***ж, ч, ш, щ*** под ударением пишется
>   буква ***е***, хотя и произносится ***о***, а именно:
>
> <…>
>
> 6. **В словах, в корне которых** под ударением произносится ***-о***, чередующееся с ***е*** в других формах или **в других словах того же
>      корня…**

Какой корень в слове ***очки***? ОЧ-? ОЧК-?

Практически все словари и того времени, и сейчас выделяют в этом слове корень ОЧК-, в образованных от ***очков*** словах ***очечник, очечный*** (пишущихся с ударным **Е**!) -- корень ОЧЕЧ.

Корень ОЧ<…>Ч, видимо, следует тогда выделять и в слове ***оч<ё/о>чки***. И какую же букву же тогда надо выбрать -- ***Ё*** или ***О***? См. ещё раз Правила -56 (выше по тексту). Похоже, нужна ***Ё***, поскольку в однокоренных с ***очёчками*** словах употреблено ***Е***.

Авторы ПАС и РОС выбрали ***О*** (введя правило о *беглом гласном*). А чтобы не вводить такое написание в исключения из правил,  установленных в [**§ 19 ПАС**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=18#pp18)

(см.: § 19. Во всех остальных случаях для передачи ударного гласного о после ***ж, ч, ш, щ*** пишется буква ***ё***, а именно: <…> 7. В тех корнях русских слов, где ударному звуку о соответствует в других однокоренных словах или формах гласный (ударный или безударный), передаваемый буквой ***е***.)

они предложили считать ***-оч-*** в слове ***очочки*** не частью корня, а **суффиксом**.

Но, похоже, такая позиция поддерживается не всеми словаристами.

См. ***"Большой универсальный словарь русского языка" под ред. Морковкина (М., 2016):***

> *Морф.* **очк-и**. *Дер. уменьш.-ласк.* **очёч|к(и)**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо,  slava, за проведенное исследование, очень всё интересно. Да, история смутная с этими "очёчками".  Корень в этом слове ОЧК, беглая гласная в корне, но при этом написание Е/Ё поддерживается словами "очечник, очечный", как и в глаголах учесть, учёт, но учту (беглая гласная). Возможно, здесь учитывается МЯГКОСТЬ Ч, потому что все примеры с беглым О в корне после ТВЕРДЫХ шипящих (княжон, кишок и т.д.).  Но порядок надо бы навести и оставить одну форму - лучше "очёчки", так как "очочки" на письме выглядят несколько странно.

Comment: @slava1947,современные словари - это какие? РОС (тот, что на Грамоте) фиксирует только: очочки. Ту же рекомендацию дает Институт русского языка. ОчЕчки через Ё  я нашел только в словаре синонимов на академике.

Comment: И еще: что такое "дер"  в вашем скриншоте?

Comment: _Серж: современные словари - это какие?_ === См. мой ответ.

Comment: _Серж: Ту же рекомендацию дает Институт русского языка._ === Вы имеете в виду ИРЯ им. Виноградова, выпустивший РОС? Есть ещё Гос. ИРЯ им. Пушкина, подготовивший и выпустивший  "Большой универсальный словарь русского языка", выдержку из которого я привёл в своём ответе.

Comment: _Серж: И еще: что такое "дер" в вашем скриншоте?_ ===  ДЕРИВАТ. См.  http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82

Comment: Да,  ИРЯ им. Виноградова.

Comment: Не могу понять: какой смысл было предлагать считать -оч- суффиксом?

Comment: Зять, будто ёж, недовольно посверкивал глазами сквозь ***очочки***: даже рюмка водки не сняла внутреннего напряжения. В. В. Личутин, «Любостай», 1987 г.

Comment: Тогда как объяснить написание через о в 1987, тогда тоже не было ни РАН, ни РОС?

Answer (score 0):

Очочки от очки. Сейчас корень "очк/очоч"+ суффикс "к", но ведь понятно, что слово "очки" образовано от слова "очи". Исторический корень "оч", остальное суффиксы, которые переразложились, в суффиксах пишется "о" после шипящих. Поэтому логичнее писать с "о".